# Eagle Gerber Files Warnings

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, gerber

This is my first time to get a gerber output from a .brd.

I've followed this way: Cam Processor -> Load JobFile -> Local Cam Jobs -> Examples -> Legacy -> gerb274x.cam

I've encountered two warnings here: 
[image]

[image]

I've fixed first warning with taking the files that stand on legacy part to gerber part with the recovery icon next to them. Can be seen in pic.

Fixed second warning as program adviced, generate excellon outputs based on pcb stackup.

after all, processed the job and I get:  .sts  .stc  .sol  .pls  .plc  .drl  .cmp  .xln  .gbrjob 9 files in total.

my question is am I doing right all the process?

Because when I select "two layer deafult" in templates, I got no warnings what's the difference between them?

If you have another advice to export gerber files I can gladly follow.